# Sharing an AngularJS factory between controllers

Tags: angularjs

I have two controllers and a factory with some utility functions I use in both controllers. One of the utility functions checks the cache (`$cacheFactory`) for some value, and I can't get it to work, no matter what.

**app:**

```
angular.module('sfmiet', ['sfmiet.autocomplete', 'sfmiet.httpservice', 'sfmiet.utilservice']);
```

**factory:**

```
angular.module('sfmiet.utilservice', [])
    .factory('utilservice', ['$cacheFactory',  function($cacheFactory) {

        return function(cacheName) {

            this.cache = $cacheFactory.get(cacheName);

            this.init = function(cacheName) {
                this.cache = $cacheFactory.get(cacheName);
            };

            this.isActiveStep = function(step) {
                return (this.cache.get('step') == step);    
            };
        };
}]);
```

**controller 1:**

```
angular.module('sfmiet').controller('sftestCtrl', function($scope, $cacheFactory, utilservice) {

    $scope.util = new utilservice('stateCache');    
    console.log($scope.util);

    //some more stuff...
});
```

**controller 2:**

```
angular.module('sfmiet').controller('sfmietCtrl', function($scope, $timeout, $http, $cacheFactory, autocomplete, httpservice, utilservice) {

    $scope.util = new utilservice('stateCache');
    console.log($scope.util);

    //some more stuff...
});
```

logging `$scope.util.cache` for the controllers gives me an object for the second but *undefined* for the first. Not using the new keyword leaves `$scope.util` completely *undefined* for the first controller, while again beeing fine with the second. All works fine with only one controller, but as soon as I bring the second in, it stops working.

Maybe I'm missing something here, but I can't see the reason for this behavior. Been searching the web for the last 3 hours, and since I'm at the end of my rope now, I hope you people can give me a poke. Thanks very much!

Comment: Do you have any plunkr/fiddle for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$cacheFactory), `$cacheFactory.get` returns `undefined` if the cache does not exist.

The most likely cause is that `stateCache` is created after your first controller, and before your second controller.

Comment: You are right, i completely missed that. Thank you very much! Is there a better Place to create it, btw, than Inside a controller, so it won't depend in their Order?

Comment: In this case, I would create it inside the utilService. Due to the dependencies from both controllers on the utilService, this is guaranteed to be instantiated first.  In that case, you might want to use `.service` instead of `.factory`, so all the `new` stuff is handled for you